# Objects and arrays addition

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain to me how the results of the following was evaluated?

```
{} + {} // NaN
[] + {} // "[object Object]"
{} + [] // 0
[] + [] // ""
```

Comment: I think `{} + []` is actually `"0"` (a string) not `0` (a number).

Comment: @DaoWen, it's actually an Integer `0`

Comment: no sir, its an integer, test it in the chromes console if you like ..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a full explanation of this, [check it](http://www.2ality.com/2012/01/object-plus-object.html).

***And note*** `{} + {}` be `NaN` if you execute it directly in the console because `{}` is thought of a block rather than an object.

`({}+{})` should be `'[object Object][object Object]'`

***The real result is***:

```
console.log({}+{}) // '[object Object][object Object]'
console.log([]+{}) // '[object Object]'
console.log({}+[]) // '[object Object]'
console.log([]+[]) // ''
```

Comment: The it's-a-block-not-object thing is a great catch! Thanks!

Comment: Another link for description: https://loomcom.com/blog/2015/06/29/the-wats-of-javascript/

Answer (score 3):

Adding arrays with any object and its string representation always results in a join

For example:

```
[1] + [2] // is merged to "12", so [] + [] is an empty string ""
```

The same equals for your second example

```
['test'] + {} // "test[object Object]"
```

So an empty array plus an empty object  will just return an `[object Object]`

---

For adding to empty objects it's easy too:

Evaluate a simple empty object: `{} // results in undefined`

And adding two `undefined` values is `NaN` because  there's no way you can make an addition on them.

**Note**: The return values depend on the implementation of JavaScript (i.e. in which Browser or Environment)

Also: [**What is {} + {} in JavaScript?**](http://www.2ality.com/2012/01/object-plus-object.html)

Answer (score 3):

For `{}+{}`, the first `{}` is interpreted as a block, the second `{}` is interpreted as an empty object and the `+` is interpreted as a [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()), so `{}+{}` is equivalent to:

```
{
    //Empty block, does nothing
}

+{}    //Unary + applied to empty object, which is NaN
```

Similarly, in `{}+[]`, the `{}` is interpreted as a block and `+[]` is interpreted as the unary plus operator applied to an empty array, which gives `0`.

For `[]+{}`, the `+` is interpreted as a string concatenation operator, so both the operands are converted to strings, in this case `[]` get converted to the empty string (`""`) and `{}` gets converted to `"[object Object]"`, then both are concatenated together giving `""+"[object Object]"` which is `"[object Object]"`.

Similarly, for `[]+[]`, both arrays get converted to the empty string, giving `""+""` which is `""`.

Answer (score 0):

```
{} + {}
```

you can't make an addition or any operation on two object

```
[] + {} // "[object Object]"
```

it's just a concat between a string and a object, you have the same result with `alert({});`

```
{} + [] // 0
```

same

```
[] + [] // ""
```

concat of two empty string = empty string.