# Why result of ({} + []) not equal to ([] + {})

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

Javascript addition operation is easy to understand if there are only string and numbers or booleans.

But things getting harder with objects and arrays.

I looked into spec [ECMA Script 3, 1999](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) 11.6.1 and into Douglas Crockford [Enciclopedia](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/encyclopedia/#2B) but both provided algorithms do not explain why:

```
[] + {}  // "[object Object]"
{} + []  // 0
{} + 0   // 0
0 + {}   // "0[object Object]"

{} + {}  // NaN, but not either 0 or "[object Object][object Object]"
```

Is anyone can explain this?

Comment: When you add Apples to Oranges, you get fruit Salad. And two Salads are never equal :)

Comment: Aside: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: According with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11930789/4224126) answer you have a full explanation [here](http://www.2ality.com/2012/01/object-plus-object.html)

Comment: Adrian Menendez thanks very much, I saw your answer, sorry for delay, I'm trying figured this out

Comment: You're welcome nahab, there is a good explanation on the Axel Rauschmayer post.